# on Jenkins not able to run the batch file which contains TestNG XML file created for taking screen shot

Tags: jenkins

I have created one selenium script which takes a screenshot and I have to run this script on jenkin.but when I run this script on Jenkin the test case failed and if I run the same script on eclipse it is running successfully and taking the screenshot. so my question is can we run the selenium script on Jenkin which takes the screenshot?

```
:~/eclipse-workspace/seffcon$ java -cp /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/bin:/home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/libs/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
[TestNG] Running:
  /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/testng.xml


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

[libs jar file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRYAb.png)

Comment: of course you can, but how can we help if we dont see any code or configuration you have done?? Please share more info if you are expecting some help

Comment: the normal code is working easily but when i add ashot jar files in libs folder for taking the screenshot the test case failed. please suggest me how can i run this type of script on Jenkins

Comment: may be jenkins is not loading your jars . why don't you use maven?

Comment: the test case where i have to check the text present or not/button present or not are also getting failed in Jenkins. can u please how can i run this case